# MVC Core DbContext disposed between function calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, dispose

I have a pretty simple service that creates and entity and assigns an alpahnumeric sequence to a property then persists the entity to the db. The context is injected into the service via the MVC Core dependency injection like so.

```
// Configure DB context
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<MyDataContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly)));
```

The context is initialized in the service constructor via

```
public MyService(MyDataContext myDataContext)
{
    this.myDataContext = myDataContext;   
}
```

The logic to perform the insert is as follows

```
public async Task  GenerateRecord()
 {
    // Init the entity
    var myEntity = new myEntity
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
        Sequence = await GetSequence();
    };

     myDataContext.MyEntities.Add(myEntity);
     myDataContext.SaveChanges();

 }
```

The logic to generate the sequence is

```
private async Task<string> GetSequence()
{

    DbCommand cmd = myDataContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.fnGetAlphaNumSeqID";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    DbParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
    param.Value = "";
    param.DbType = DbType.String;
    param.Size = 100;
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    param.ParameterName = "@ReturnSequence";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

    if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
    }
    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

    var newId = param.Value.ToString();

    return newId;

}
```

The problem that I am running into is that, after the call to `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` the context is disposed. I am awaiting the only async call in the function and am returning `async Task` as opposed to `async void`. I am currently unable to determine the appropriate method for getting this to succeed or why the context is being disposed of when it is not being utilized in a `using()` statement and am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: `myDataContext.SaveChanges();` is failing with ""Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances. Object name: 'MyDataContext'."

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I fail to reproduce your issue with these code. Try to add `try catch` block around `GetSequence()` to check whether there is any error during this action which may dispose the dbcontext. Check whether `myEntity` get expected value from `GetSequence()`.